# Script to generate a MATRIX

Tags: c#, powershell

I wish to have a script to generate all possible possibility from 'NxN' matrix using powershell.

I couldn't find anything over the web, and don't have anything to start with.

does anyone has something similar?

Edit: 
Lets say I have 2x2 matrix, the possibilities are:

```
1 1|
1 2|
2 1|
2 2|
```

lets say I have 10 strings... each string has `1` or `0` for value, I wish to extract/generate all possible combinations.

Comment: Read you own question, pretending you didn't already know what you want ... would you understand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# For read from cmd
param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [int] $inputvalue)

if($inputvalue){$matrixheight = "$inputvalue"}
else{$matrixheight = read-host -prompt "What is size of matrix...?"}

For($i = 1; $i -le $matrixheight; $i ++){
    For($j = 1; $j -le $matrixheight; $j ++){
        Write-Host "$i" "$j" "|"
    }
}
```